# How to do a HTTPS post on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am trying to do a HTTPS post on ESP8266 as shown in Postman below

[image: picture from Postman]

But I keep getting: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'.

Can someone please help me with how to build up the headers correctly in the HTTPS POST? And maybe also give a link to some documentation? I cant seem to find any...

My code is:

```
const char* host = "api.dgs.com";
const int httpsPort = 443;
String url = "/ccs-int/v1/applicationdatalogging/1.0";
String msg = "";

WiFiClientSecure client;

Serial.print("connecting to : '");
Serial.print(host);
Serial.println("'");
Serial.printf("Using fingerprint '%s'\n", fingerprint);
client.setFingerprint(fingerprint);

client.connect(host, httpsPort);

Serial.print("requesting URL: '");
Serial.print(url);
Serial.println("'");

client.print(String("POST ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
    "Connection: close\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/json" +
    "Authorization: Bearer " + authorization_code + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Length: " + msg.length() + "\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    msg + "\r\n");

Serial.println("request sent");
unsigned long timeout = millis();
while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
        Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
        client.stop();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unauthorized says it all. I can't see anything for authorization in your code

Comment: And the documentation you've asked https://httpstatuses.com/401

Comment: If you're getting to the point that you get a 401 back, HTTPS is succeeding. 'Unauthorized' should mean that there's an issue with your authorization code. Do you have access to a computer that can run curl? If you do, try doing this post from that. It would be something like `curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer AUTHCODE" --header "Content-Length: 0" https://api.dgs.com/ccs-int/v1/applicationdatalogging/1.0` replacing `AUTHCODE` with your authorization code. This may help you debug what's going on with it.

Comment: I moved the autorization part up earlier in the 'client.print', which fixed the problem. However now I get a 411 error (Content-length has to be specified). Any idea what might be my new problem? I have specified the content length and I have also tried different values with no success.

Comment: @T.Krebs...can you share the full code example, It's a bit difficult to figure out which portion is setup and which is loop.